# Android studio appcombat actionbar setup

Tags: java, android

I've managed somehow to add the action bar when i extend `ActionBarAtcitivy`, but what if i want to call for example: `ListActivity` and still have the action bar?

I have a strange feeling that i missed something when i added the appcombat library, because in the preview design window actionbar is never displayed, though if i launch the app, the action bar is there(But only if i extended the  ActionBarActivity).

How i installed the actionbar:

1. I downloaded the library and the repository.
2. I added the compile `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3` in `build.gradle`.
3. I have the  `android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="21"` declared in my `build.gradle` script.

Ive done these parts, as told in the android studio documentation.

Another interesting thing, when i'm trying to import the `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` it just disappears immediately. whatsthat about?

Comment: `appcombat` ... Insert coin. Ready? Fight!

Answer (score 2):

You need to stick with `ActionBarActivity` if you want to use this library. For your particular case, instead of having a `ListActivity`, you should:

- have an activity extending `ActionBarActivity`;
- load a `ListFragment` into it, possibly from the support libraries as well (`android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`).

Regarding your second question, the "design" view will not show your toolbar if you load that at runtime. It just reads your layout XML file without running any code, according to the theme you have set. It should not be intended as a real, reliable preview of what your activity will look like. For that you need an emulator running the OS, or a real phone.

Comment: You could also get rid of ListFragment and use **normal ListViews**, which give you more control...